# NSMutableURLRequest Unsupported URL

Tags: ios, objective-c, openweathermap

I'm using the Open Weather Map API to fetch the user's current weather.

When I run the request in Postman, I get a status code 200 and am able to receive data. However, in Xcode I get the error -1002

Here is the code executing the 'GET' request:

```
// Configure URL String
NSString *apiKey = @"MY_API_KEY";
NSString *urlString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?APPID=%@&lat=%@&lon=%@", apiKey, latitude, longitude]; 
NSString *encodedUrl = [urlString stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet]];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:encodedUrl];
NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

[theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];

NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];

[[session dataTaskWithRequest:theRequest completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
    if(data != nil) {
        NSDictionary *jsonDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];
        NSLog(@"Here is the json dict: %@", jsonDict);
        NSLog(@"%@", response);
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"error: %@", error);
    }
}] resume];
```

Again, the request here returns the error but in Postman I get no error when I run:

api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?APPID=MY_API_KEY&lat=33.712926&lon=-117.839181

What is the issue with how I'm setting up the request?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A URL needs a scheme part. Please make sure you include a protocol such as `http` or `https` in your URL string:

```
NSString *urlString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?APPID=%@&lat=%@&lon=%@", apiKey, latitude, longitude];
```

Comment: I cannot believe I missed this. I tried this earlier but that failed because my request could not reach their servers with the "www." addition. Thank you so much for this!

Comment: Kamchatka, this "protocol part" is called the "scheme" of the URL.

Comment: @Rob I had to wait 8 minutes before I could accept - got sidetracked but just came back to accept!